# Loop repeated code to set userform checkbox values

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I've a dashboard that uses a userform box field with checkboxes to choose what data to display on a chart.

My code is very copy and pasted.

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
UserForm1.Show
If Worksheets("Data Directorate").Range("X4").Value = True Then UserForm1.CheckBox1 = True
If Worksheets("Data Directorate").Range("X5").Value = True Then UserForm1.CheckBox2 = True
If Worksheets("Data Directorate").Range("X6").Value = True Then UserForm1.CheckBox3 = True
```

Is there a way to use a loop to do this?

I've more repeated code later on:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
  Select Case CheckBox1.Value
  Case True
  Worksheets("Data Directorate").Range("X4").Value = True
  Case False
  Worksheets("Data Directorate").Range("X4").Value = False
End Select
End Sub
```

This repeats for 24 check boxes. Would it be possible to loop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach in this scenario would be:

Set `ControlSource` property of the checkboxes to appropriate cells, leave only:
`UserForm1.Show`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's so much simpler than coding! I had no idea what ControlSource was. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

All great advice posted in this thread, so I'd like to add something that can maybe help to simplify your loops. Controls have a `Tag` property which, as best I can tell, does nothing other than to store additional information about the control.

Using this to our advantage, we can include the linked cell in the `Tag` property for each checkbox. (For example, enter `X4` into the `Tag` for linkage to cell `X4`). This permits for less of the information to be hardcoded, which makes it more adaptable.

Finally, the code would look like this.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    For Each octrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(octrl) = "CheckBox" Then
            Sheet1.Range(octrl.Tag).Value = octrl.Value
        End If

    Next octrl
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, very nice, I have never thought of this! Thanks!

Comment: Excellent! Never knew this existed! I would throw some error checking around it, as there's no guarantee the form editor (person) would remember to set every CheckBox's `.tag` property - especially if it's being modified at some point in the future...

Comment: @FreeMan I definitely agree. I usually expect that the poster will take the advice and develop it as necessary. Error checking is a must otherwise an empty tag will throw an exception.

Comment: @FreeMan Sorry I'm new to this, what do you mean by some "error checking" and a CheckBox's 'tag' property

Comment: @PatSearle, this answer relies on you setting the `.tag` property of the checkbox = to the cell that stores its checked value. Since it relies on you (or someone maintaining after you) to manually set this up, it's worth writing some code around the statements to ensure that `.tag` has actually been set to a usable value before trying to use it. i.e. make sure you have a useable value before trying to use it.

Comment: @PatSearle if you look at the screenshot in your accepted answer, it shows the `properties` for the check box. Near the bottom of the list, between `TabStop` and `TextAlign` is the `Tag` property. You can put any value you'd like in there and it can mean anything you want. This answer suggests using it to store the cell reference you'd like to use to permanently store the checkbox's value. Using the `Tag` property would be very similar to the `ControlSource` property you chose to use, but requires more manual effort on your part. Your choice was wise.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to simplify: instead of using If statements, just make the two sides equal. Like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
UserForm1.Show

UserForm1.CheckBox1 = Worksheets("Data Directorate").Range("X4").Value
```

And the other one:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
  Worksheets("Data Directorate").Range("X4").Value = CheckBox1.Value
End Sub
```

I recommend using the change event instead of the click event. Some user might use `Tab` and `Space`, then the click event won't trigger. Like this:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()
...
```

About looping through the checkboxes in the CommandButton21_Click event, that depends on the order of your checkboxes and your table. This might work, but you will have to try it on your table (the order of the checkboxes compared to the order of your cells can ruin the game...)

```
Dim contr As control
dim i as integer
i=4
For Each contr In UserForm1.Controls
  If TypeName(contr) = "CheckBox" Then
    contr.Value = cells(i,24).Value 'column 24 is column X
    i=i+1
  End If
Next
```

A possible variation to work when CheckBoxes are not in the expected order or get added/removed:

```
Dim contr As control
Dim J as Integer
Dim Offset as Integer

Offset = 3  'set this to the difference between 1 and the first row containing data

For Each contr In UserForm1.Controls
  If TypeName(contr) = "CheckBox" Then
    'set j to the checkboxes "number"
    J = cInt(right(contr.name, len(contr.name) - len("CheckBox")))
    'use the checkbox number + offset to find the row we want
    contr.Value = cells(J + Offset,24).Value 'column 24 is column X
  End If
Next
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your last loop is clever, but _very_ dependent on control order! While it may work the first time, any future changes to the form could break it.

Comment: Yes, but that is basically true to any loop trying to iterate checkboxes. That is why I wouldn't recommend using it. Just go with the copy-paste, withouth `If` statements.

Comment: Cool... You mentioned it, I was just trying to emphasize it for the newbies. I'm going to edit in a change that will work for this particular question (and others with slight modification). Feel free to remove the edit if you don't like it.

Comment: @FreeMan and vacip. I like to use the `Tag` property to link the cell directly to the control, rather than linking them in a hardcoded manner in the actual source code. See my solution below for an alternative option.

Answer (score 0):

For the second portion of your question:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
  Worksheets("Data Directorate").Range("X4").Value = CheckBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: In that top one i need to cycle through different X values as well as CheckBox values. for example X4=CheckBox1, X5=CheckBox2.

I could get the X part to loop but when I tried to add another integer e.g. CheckBoxL, it wouldn't cycle through. It just said CheckBoxL can't be found

Comment: Yup, saw that and edited. Use [Jeanno](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30507270/2344413)'s answer for that, and mine for your second issue

Answer (score 0):

You can group the checkboxes inside a given frame and try the the following

```
Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long
    i = 5
    For Each cb In UserForm1.Frame1.Controls
        If Worksheets("Data Directorate").Range("X" & i).Value = True Then cb.Value = True
        i = i + 1
    Next cb
End Sub
```

Comment: No need for the If statement here, just make the two sides equal. Also, `cells(i,26)` is somewhat faster than `range("X" & i)`.